# Saving multidimensional array to Cookie to be called back for display?

Tags: jquery, forms, cookies, multidimensional-array, onload

I have a form that will push items into a multi-dimensional array, but I don't know how to save it to a cookie to be called back again later upon reloading the page.

```
function addit(form) {
    upperlimit = upperlimit + 1
original[original.length++] =  new input(form.Title.value, form.Artist.value, form.Ddate.value, form.Genre.value, form.Picsrc.value)
alert("your entry has been added")
saveIt()
clearform()
}
```

Cookie function?

```
function saveIt() {
var x = original;//this is a multi-dimensional array
    $.cookie("data",original);
    alert($.cookie("data"));}
```

need to somehow call back and load the cookie into the array to be able to carry out a display:

```
$("#info").html(original[currentrecord].Title+"<br /><h2>"+original[currentrecord].Artist+"</h2>"+original[currentrecord].Ddate+"<br />"+original[currentrecord].Genre) ;
```

By the way, when I just do an alert for the array (  alert(original)  ), it shows up as [object Object] if that influences what is being saved to the cookie?

Answer (score 4):

before writing your object to a coockie (it's an object, not an array), just do this

```
var x = JSON.stringify(original);
```

To use it as an object again:

```
var back2orig = JSON.parse($.cookie('data'));
```

That's all there is to it... google JSON, you'll love it :)

Comment: Out of all the solutions I read to store an array in a cookie, this is by far the best answer.